# ¿Cómo integrar js_composer a un tema wordpress creado desde cero?

Tags: wordpress

Estoy realizando un proyecto de desarrollo al cual le realicé un diseño personalizado, este sistema debe quedar administrable, para lograr este fin empecé a crear un tema para wordpress basándome en diseño que cree. Cuando ya tengo todo montado decidí usar el js_composer para que los editores puedan administrar mejor el contenido, el problema que tengo es que cuando se crea una página y en esta se agregan elementos de js_composer estos no se muestran en el front de la manera que se deberían mostrar, salen desordenados y sin estilos, estoy seguro que el problema es porque no se están incrustando los CSS y JS correspondiente en el front de la página. Estuve revisando themas que funcionan perfectamente con el js_composer y veo que se incrusta el JS y el CSS que se encuentra en la carpeta:

> /plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.min.css

y

> /plugins/js_composer/assets/js/dist/js_composer_front.min.js

así que en mi código lo realicé de esta manera:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html  <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
        <head>
            <meta charset="<?php echo bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
            <meta content="#0E47AE" name="theme-color">
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
            <title>Proyecto web- <?php echo wp_title(); ?></title>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Staatliches|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/style.css">

 <!-- acá se supone que está el css de js_composer-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/../../plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.min.css?ver=5.6">

        </head>
```

Y en el footer va lo siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.tm.horizon.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.tm.counter.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js"></script>


      <!-- Este se supone que es el javascript de js_composer-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/../../plugins/js_composer/assets/js/dist/js_composer_front.min.js?ver=5.6"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

la cosa es que no me está interpretando el diseño que debería salir. La verdad no soy experto en creación de temas para wordpress, me gustaría que alguien que conóce el tema me pueda ayudar con esto.

Gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 0):

Te hace falta agregar `<?php wp_head(); ?>` en el header.php antes de cerrar el `</head>` y `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` en el footer antes de cerrar el `</body>`.

Comment: Mucha gracias, voy a revisar y le cuento.